# В заданной строке вместо первого символа поставить пробел

Tags: c++

```
void main(){
    char str[80] = "fae*fe fief oq eof jiqe[ qe";
    char token[80];

    char *p = str;
    char *t = token;

    cout << str << endl;

    while (*p){
        if (*p == p[0]) // меняем 1 символ с индексом [0] на пробел.
            *p = ' ';
        *t = *p;
        ++t; ++p;
    }
    *t = 0;

    cout << token << endl;

}
```

Почему у меня указатель p, равен p[0], если это индекс на 1 символ?

Comment: Какая поставлена задача?

Comment: Если вы пишете на C++, то пользуйтесь правильными строками. `char[]` — это **не** строка C++.

Comment: @VladD  Если вы пишите на C++, то пользуйтесь правильными терминами. Строка - это набор символов, завершающихся нулевым символом. Так что символьный массив может содержать, как вы сказали, "правильную строку". Объекты класса std:;string - это именно объекты этого класса, а не строки.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Насколько я себе представляю, строка в C++ и есть объект `std::string`. То, что язык C называет массив символов строкой, это подробности языка C. То, что C++ поддерживает также и C-style strings — это печальное последствие заявленной «совместимости».

Comment: @VladD Использование в таком контексте термина строка вносит путаницу. Символьные массивы не обязательно содержат строки. Так что уже в самом C есть разделение понятий символьных массивов и строк.  Более того если в C для инициализации символьного массива используется строковый литерал, то совершенно не обязательно, что сам символьный массив включит в себя завершающий 0. Он может быть исключен из инициализации массива.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Мне кажется, никакой путаницы. Строка в C++ одна и только одна: `std::string`. Понятие, на которое вы ссылаетесь — это «сишная строка», не имеет ничего общего с понятием «строка» в контексте C++.

Comment: @VladD std:;string - это не строка. Это контейнер для строк. Таким же контейнером может быть символьный массив. Понятие строки одинаково для C и C++, точно также, как и понятие строкового литерала. Строковый литерал - это и есть строка, записанная как литерал.

Comment: @VladD Чтобы было более понятно, сравни два объявления в C. char s[6] = "Hello"; и char s[5] = "Hello";  Про первое объявление мы говорим, что массив содержит строку, тогда как про второе объявление мы не можем сказать то же самое. Массив из второго объявления не содержит строки.

Comment: "Почему у меня указатель p, равен p[0], если это индекс на 1 символ?" - что означает эта фраза? Несколько раз прочитал - не понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего функция `main` должна иметь тип возвращаемого значения `int`

```
int main()
{
    //...
}
```

Что касается самой программы, то она не имеет смысла, так как условие в if предложении

```
if (*p == p[0]) // меняем 1 символ с индексом [0] на пробел.
```

будет всегда истинно, так как конструкции `*p` и `p[0]` эквивалентны и возвращают ссылку на элемент, на который указывает указатель `p`.

Поэтому отвечая на ваш вопрос

> Почему у меня указатель p, равен p[0], если это индекс на 1 символ?

скажу, что в цикле указатель `p` постоянно инкрементируется

```
++t; ++p;
```

так что `p[0]` - это только в самом начале цикла указывает на первый элемент строки. Далее в цикле `p[0]` - это текущий символ, который соответствует увеличенному значению указателя `p`

Если вы хотели написать программу, которая копирует исходную строку в выходную строку, заменяя в выходной строке все символы, которые равны первому символу исходной строки пробелом, то функция `main` могла бы выглядеть следующим образом

```
int main()
{
    char str[80] = "fae*fe fief oq eof jiqe[ qe";
    char token[80];

    cout << str << endl;

    const char *p = str;
    char *t = token;

    do
    {
        *t++ = ( *p == str[0] ? ' ' : *p );
    } while ( *p++ ); 

    cout << token << endl;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что лучше использовать цикл `do-while`, так как в любом случая одна итерация цикла должна быть для завершающего нулевого символа строки `'\0'`.

Тоже самое можно сделать с помощью стандартного алгоритма `std::replace_copy`, объявленному в заголовке `<algorithm>`

Если же вы хотели заменить именно только первый символ пробелом в выходной строке, то можно это было бы сделать так

```
int main()
{
    char str[80] = "fae*fe fief oq eof jiqe[ qe";
    char token[80];

    cout << str << endl;

    const char *p = str;
    char *t = token;
    *t++ = ( *p ? ' ' : *p ); 

    while ( *p++ )
    {
        *t++ = *p;
    }; 

    cout << token << endl;
}
```

Comment: Good to see you on this site :) Figured I'd lurk here too to work on my Russian. Also, +1.

Comment: @Barry  Thanks, Barry . I am glad to see you. I am here for the first time.:)

Answer (score 1):

Вы запутались с адресной арифметикой. Выражение `p[n]` эквивалентно `*(p + n)`. В вашем случае, `p[0] == *(p + 0) == *p`.

Полагаю, вместо `p[0]` Вы хотели написать `str[0]`. Также, если вам нужно заменить **только** первый символ, нет нужды проверять его каждый раз в цикле, потому что первый символ (если и существует), то только один. Если Вы хотите заменить все символы, эквивалентные первому, Вам стоит изменить заголовок вопроса.

Comment: Я хочу понять принцип работы указателей

Comment: Вопрос достаточно обширный. Вас интересует адресная арифметика,  или как указатели работают на низком уровне?

Answer (score 1):

char *p = str; это адрес на нулевой символ,
если хочешь на первый, сделай ++p после получения адреса.
Ты там первый символ сразу пробелом сделал. И весь последующий цикл потерял смысл.
p[0] сохрани в другую переменную tmpChar например, и делай if (*p == tmpChar)